# how to read element value from xml schema?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this following response , and I want to read only success element using javascript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <OTA_HotelResNotifRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://www.openvel.org/OTA/2003/05" EchoToken="'.$reference.'" TimeStamp="'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'" Version="1.0">
            <Success>'.$Meassage.'</Success>
            </OTA_HotelResNotifRS>
```

Comment: Is the xml response is string?.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this tutorial?
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Using `DOMParser`, I have tried your XML string in JSFiddle, hope that helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/3duxcbop/

Comment: Thank You for your answer,but "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined" getting this error after implementing your solution.

Comment: Could there be some formatting problems among the given XML string? If you're using string literals like in my JSFiddle example, be sure to properly escape all quotation marks.